# Accessing a key's value in local storage on click, isn't working as planned

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to create a simple message board with javascript using local storage, a user types their name, and some text and it displays below the form.

When I click the remove button instead of logging the text its logging "remove" (the text content of the button)
I have a variable named text that should hold the text of the message submitted by a the user, I cannot find out whats going wrong here.

```
**function removeMessage(text){
    console.log(text);
}**


function fetchMessages(){
    let messages=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('messages'));
    const messageBoard=document.querySelector('#messageBoard');
    messageBoard.innerHTML="";
    for(let i=0; i<messages.length; i++){
        const name= messages[i].name;
        **const text=messages[i].text;**
        messageBoard.innerHTML+=
        `<div class="all">
            <div class="names">
                <h3>${name}</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="messages">
                <p>${text}</p>
                </div>
            <div class="button">
                **<a onclick="removeMessage(text)" href="#" id="delete">Remove</a>**
            </div>
        </div>`;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a global variable called `text` when you click `<a onclick="removeMessage(text)" href="#" id="delete">Remove</a>`, the `text` refers to `this.text` of the `<a>` element, which is `Remove`. Maybe you should replace `removeMessage(text)` with `removeMessage(${text})` or use some sort of index pointing to that entry.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you..one more thing if you have time, or anyone else feel free to chime in, instead of logging the text, it instead gives an error of "uncaught reference error: (the text content) is undefined"

Comment: Missing quotes, should be `removeMessage(\'${text}\')`. Sorry for my mistake.